# Load the next page by scrolling down in a paginated post (an article that is split into several pages) Wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

In pagination posts (articles that are split into several pages by using the page-break), I want the next page of the article to automatically load when a user scrolls down in the article, rather than the need for the user to click the "next" button in order to move to the next page. Here are some examples of that:

- https://constative.com/lifestyle/funny-fathers-trying-to-master-parenthood-is/
- https://www.bleacherbreaker.com/trending/photos-that-people-shouldve-looked-at-a-little-longer-before-posting/

**Any idea how I can do so on a WordPress site? Any plugin? Code?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement an Infinite Scroll in wordpress:

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-infinite-scroll-to-your-wordpress-blog/